# MSflexgrid to XML file conversion

Tags: vb.net, msflexgrid

I am trying to convert MSflexgrid data to datatable or XML.

But I am not sure about this.

Can anyone please confirm me

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something like this?

```
Public Function BuildDataTable() as DataTable 

For Each myFG In FG.Rows

        MyDataTable.Rows.Add(myFG .column("ColumnName").ToString)
Next

return MyDataTable
```